# Need help with ArrayList and Stack please

Tags: java

I am having trouble starting out this program. I am supposed to write a program that will populate an `ArrayList` by asking the user for 10 numbers.

After the list is made I'm to navigate it and if a number is even number, remove it from the `ArrayList` and put the number to a `Stack` of integers. So far I have this but I am confused on how to get the stack started so that I can put the even numbers into it:

```
import java.io.* ;
import java.util.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        ArrayList<Integer> test = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Stack<Integer> myStack = new Stack<Integer>();

        System.out.print ("Enter Number: \n");

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {          //Put Into ArrayList
            test.add(input.nextInt());
        }

        System.out.print("Contents of Array: " +  test );
        System.out.print("\n");

        for (int i= 0; i < 10 ; i++) {
            int item = myIterator.getNext();
            if (item % 2 == 0) {
                myListIterator.remove(); //removes it from the ArrayList
                myStack.push(item); //puts it into the stack
            }

        }

        System.out.print("Contents of Array afer numbers removed: " +  test );
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: what problems are you having?

Comment: Unrelated, but because this is homework, I'll add this comment.  It's a good idea to get into the habit of coding to interfaces.  So instead of declaring ArrayList test = new ArrayList(), use List test = new ArrayList() instead.  Coding to interfaces gives you greater flexibility when it comes time to change the implementation.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you just need to initialize the stack.  Do the initialization of the stack where you initialize the test array.

Put this:

```
 Stack<Integer> item = new Stack <Integer> ();
```

After:

```
ArrayList<Integer> test = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

EDIT -- I was feeling generous, so I finished it for ya ;)  You were actually almost all the way there, so I don't feel I really deprived you of a learning opportunity.  The only other real thing you were missing was initializing the iterator and using it correctly.

Note the following:

-- you will see that if you use the iterator, you can just get rid of the for loop.
-- I changed the names of the variables so they are a bit easier to follow-naming is important.
-- Finally, since an ArrayList ISA List, you will notice I changed the declaration for the input values to use the interface for the declaration.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<Integer> inputValues = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Stack<Integer> evens = new Stack <Integer> ();

        System.out.print("Enter Number: \n");

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {           //Put Into ArrayList
            inputValues.add(input.nextInt());
        }

        System.out.println("Contents of Array: " + inputValues);

        Iterator<Integer> iter = inputValues.iterator();

        while(iter.hasNext()) {
            Integer currentVal = iter.next();
            if (currentVal % 2 == 0) {
                iter.remove(); //removes it from the ArrayList
                evens.push(currentVal); //puts it into the stack
            } else {
                System.out.println("No");
            }


        }

        System.out.println("List values " + inputValues);
        System.out.println("Stack values " + evens);
    }
}
```

Comment: there's many other mistakes in your code, I suggest you start reading my answer for some clues and then read your documentation again, I'm sure there's plenty of examples on how to do things right in it ;)

Comment: okay i see what your talking about. Thanks so much, I was just getting frustrated one thing i couldn't remember

Comment: @helloman, np. just be sure to learn.  1) naming is important. 2) understand the difference between interfaces and implementations. 3) iterators vs for loops etc..

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  The commented out code has a declaration and initialization of a stack that is suitable for your purposes.  It needs to be before the code that pushes stuff onto the stack.

Answer (score 0):

I really doubt your code compiles without modification. For example myListIterator and myStack aren't even declared and I don't remember java Iterators to have a getNext() method.

Before using a variable, you must first declare it and the initialize it, these operations can be both done in one line, for example : `Stack<Integer> myStack = new Stack<Integer>();`

Looking at the tags of your question, this seems to be some kind of homework, I'm sure the documentation explains all of theses steps.

And since your using a ListIterator to remove the Integer from the ArrayList, there's no need to use a for loop, you can do something like

```
while(myListIterator.hasNext()) {
    Integer item = myListIterator.next();
    if(item % 2 == 0) {
        item.remove();
        myStack.add(item);
    }
}
```